# Is Net force per unit charge zero in a conductor in the presence of a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, conductors

Let's assume there is a perfect conductor. This conductor starts moving with a constant velocity in the presence of an external electric field and magnetic field.

Generally an external magnetic field is absent, so we say that for a static conductor to be in equilibrium net electric field is zero in a conductor.

Can the same be said for net force, if we also consider the presence of an external magnetic field?

qE + q(VxB) + qEc = 0

Or if the given conductor is accelerating,

qE + q(VxB) + qEc = ma

How can a conductor distinguish between magnetic force and electrostatic force and selectively choose to oppose electric field?

E = external electric field

B = external magnetic field

Ec = electrostatic field due to rearrangement of charges

m = mass of an electron

a = acceleration of the conductor

Comment: please, use mathjax. Are you asking about the Hall effect? see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect

Comment: I haven't learnt about hall effect yet, if its related it's a coincidence.

Comment: It is not so much a coincidence as it is the name of the effect you are asking us to describe :) Let us know if you still have questions after reading about the Hall effect.